# Delay observable flow while BehaviorSubject value === false

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, akita, angular-akita

I've got an application that performs HTTP requests every 2 seconds and updates the view. Problem is, that I have to do some user-triggered CSS animations that take approximately one second and often get broken because Angular updates the DOM while the animation is running.

Im using [Akita](https://netbasal.gitbook.io/akita/) store and retrieving observables like so:

```
this.dosingVessels$ = this.dosingVesselsQuery.selectAll().pipe(*needs rxjs operator magic*);
```

and then displaying them in the component like so:

```
    <app-solving-vessel *ngFor="let vessel of solvingVessels$ | async"
                    [vessel]="vessel"
                    [ngClass]="{'animation-class': hoverId === vessel.id}">
    </app-solving-vessel>
```

How could I achieve that while the animation is ongoing:

```
animate(event, vessel) {
    this.updateView.next(false); // prevent from updating
    this.hoverId = vessel.id; // triggers animation
    timer(1000).subscribe(tick => this.updateView.next(true)); // allow normal updating
}
```

the view doesnt get updated.

I found out about delayWhen operator, but all examples are with timers and I'm not sure if it is the right way anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does `debounce` support your needs? You can pass it an Observable and your chain will wait until that Observable emits before continuing. If you need it to wait for a specific value, you need to use the `filter` operator as well.

I'm not sure where exactly in your code this is needed, but it may look like this:

```
this.dosingVesselsQuery.selectAll().pipe(
    debounce(() => 
        this.updateView
            .pipe(filter(val => val == true))
            .pipe(first())));
```

**EDIT:**

It seems your needs would better be supported by `debounce`. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Cheers, your solution works just the way I need it to. Can't give you public +1 due to my low SO score, but your contribution is deeply appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Delaying an observable subscription or delaying an observable itself is the way to help your cause visit [this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) link, which basically shows that the delay happens on for absolute time.So, basically, your code should be like

```
this.dosingVessels$ = this.dosingVesselsQuery.selectAll().pipe(delaySubscription(1000));
```

or

```
this.dosingVessels$ = this.dosingVesselsQuery.selectAll().pipe(delay(1000));
```

Comment: I don't think that this can help me. Lets say, that I get data at 0s. Then at 1.5s, user interacts with the page and causes an animation to run. In this case, i must wait for 500ms before updating the page... but what if user interacts with the page at 1.3s or at 1.9s? Then my interval can't be the same?